# How to cache view or maintain view state on history back in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using angular 2 with the [material design grid-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular2-material/grid-list) with [infinite scrolling](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-infinite-scroll) and when I select an item from the list I navigate to the detail view representing an :id in the url path. If I navigate back the list-view is reloaded and the inital state is lost.

What is the proper way of maintaining the state of the view when navigating back? Is it possible to cache the view as it is before navigation takes place?

Comment: There are plans to support that eventually but currently components are always recreated except when only a parameter in the same route is changed.

Comment: Did you find any more information on this? I am about to embark on designing a ViewStateService in my Angular app. I think its possible, but all top level navigable components will create view state and that view state will have to be passed as an input to all sub components -- so they can add to the viewstate. I think it will be messy but I don't see any alternative.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Currently I am just caching the items for one history back level and remembering the scroll position. It would be nicer if the list view would be hidden and in memory. It´s a bit cumbersome when going back and it takes a moment to reload all the scrolled items + scrolling to the new position.

Comment: Thanks. I will post when/if I get a workaround

Answer (score 4):

First, let me say that I think support for "view-state" should be a part of the framework. And it may very well be, but I haven't been able to  find it as of yet. But since I need a solution now, I have decided to roll my own. Here's how it works.

I created a ViewStateService as follows. Notice that the viewState for the service is a Map of Maps. Each top level component, that can be navigated to, has a top level map entry with the component name as the key. The map at that key is used to pass down to subcomponents to both hold their saved view state and also a place to store their view state.

```
@Injectable()
export class ViewStateService  {
  viewState : Map<string, Map<string, string> > = new Map<string, Map<string, string> >();
  constructor(){
  }

  setViewState(key : string , map : Map<string, string>){
    this.viewState.set(key, map);
  }

  getViewState(key : string) : Map<string, string>{
    return this.viewState.get(key);
  }
}
```

Then in top level components, this service is injected. The top level component then extracts its view state in ngOnInit() by the call:

```
this.viewState = this.viewStateServices.getViewState("ComponentName");
```

This map is handed down as an input to each subcomponent (or at least the ones that need to save viewState). The subcomponents all implement OnInit and OnDestroy. In ngOnInit() they retrieve the saved view state -- if its there. And in ngOnDestroy() they save all the viewstate they want. Each subcomponent also passes the viewstate as an input to sub-subcomponents (recursively). In this way every subcomponent gets a chance to save and restore viewstate. One thing to watch out for is components that try to save a value by the same name. You can alleviate this by prefixing all fields with the component name, or some other such convention.

I have done this for my Angular app and it appears to be working satisfactorily. However, I think that the framework really ought to provide this mechanism. If and when it does (or when I figure out how it works) I plan to switch over to using it. But in the meantime, I have a solution that works.

Comment: this method is impressive. can i further know how do you actually implement this? like how do you pass in a component to the viewStateService?

Comment: Its explained as well as I can above. Top navigable component has a view state member. This member is passed as an input to each sub component. sub components, must in turn, pass to sub-sub components, etc. That is the messy part. But it does work.

Answer (score 2):

This is theoretically possible but I haven't tried yet.

If you put your detail view as a child route or a component, your list view component will not be destroyed on child route/component init. Then you could hide the parent component and navigate to child. Although this is not a proper solution and you must find a way to save list view's state.